# Syntax error on T-SQL with GROUP, DISTINCT and HAVING

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a login table with a date and an Employee Number.  What I need is a count of how many unique employee logins there were, for each month and year, for logins starting in 2014.

This is as far as I have been able to get:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS 'Year', MONTH(Date) AS 'Month', COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS EmpCount
FROM [Logins].[dbo].[tblPortalLog]
GROUP BY 'Year', 'Month'
having 'Year' >= '2014';
```

...but I get the error: "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

I googled for that error but I still haven't been able to figure out how to change the SQL so that I get exactly what I want.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers!  All three of them worked fine and produced identical data, so I voted them all up.  I didn't want to have three checked, so I just had to choose the first one that came in.  Also, Adam's was a bit faster, which is much appreciated in a data table with almost ten million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using double quotes or [] instead of single quotes around your alias (edit: in the having clause).  Single quotes indicate string values. Also, for portability you should probably use the actual expression instead of the alias in your group by.

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS [Year], MONTH(Date) AS [Month], COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS EmpCount 
FROM [Logins].[dbo].[tblPortalLog] 
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) 
HAVING YEAR(Date) >= '2014'
```

Also as noted in another answer, your condition should probably be in the `WHERE` clause instead of the `HAVING`.  Additionally, comparing the raw date is most likely faster.

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS [Year], MONTH(Date) AS [Month], COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS EmpCount 
FROM [Logins].[dbo].[tblPortalLog] 
WHERE Date >= '20140101'
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: It would probably be better to change the where clause to: Where Date >= '20140101' and Date < '20150101'

Comment: @GMastros If there's index on that column - then yes.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Even if there isn't an index on it now, there may be some day.

Comment: @GMastros Can't argue.

Comment: Good point fixing now.  Though OP wants 2014 onwards, so no need for the second bound @GMastros

Answer (score 1):

First, use a "where clause" to work with only the data you need.
Then, when using "group by clause", you can't refer to column alias that appear in "select clause". You have to repeat the formula. In this case the formula is "YEAR(Date)".

```
SELECT  Year     = YEAR([Date]), 
        Month    = MONTH([Date]), 
        EmpCount = COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID)
FROM [Logins].[dbo].[tblPortalLog] 
WHERE YEAR([Date]) >= 2014
GROUP BY    YEAR([Date]), 
            MONTH([Date])
```

N.B : I added square brackets around date because it is a reserved world.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not correct, first of all.

You're grouping not by `YEAR(Date)` and `MONTH(Date)`, but by strings `'Year'` and `'Month'`. This is the reason why you're getting your error. How do you fix it?

Quite simple. This is correct query:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS [Year], MONTH(Date) AS [Month], COUNT(DISTINCT [EmpID]) AS [EmpCount]
FROM [Logins].[dbo].[tblPortalLog]
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
HAVING YEAR(Date) >= '2014';
```

If you want to *beautify* it a bit and make your aliases usable, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to achieve that:

```
SELECT T.[Year], T.[Month], COUNT(DISTINCT [EmpID]) AS [EmpCount]
FROM [Logins].[dbo].[tblPortalLog]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT YEAR(Date) AS [Year], MONTH(Date) AS [Month]
    ) AS T
GROUP BY T.[Year], T.[Month]
HAVING T.[Year] >= '2014';
```

The reason why you can't use aliases in `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses is natural query processing order, which is:

1. `FROM`
2. `ON`
3. `OUTER`
4. `WHERE`
5. `GROUP BY`
6. `CUBE` | `ROLLUP`
7. `HAVING`
8. `SELECT`
9. `DISTINCT`
10. `ORDER BY`
11. `TOP`

You can see that `SELECT` comes after `GROUP BY`, and you're creating aliases exactly in `SELECT` statement, thus making them unusable in `GROUP BY`.